# Port fowarding and load balancer in ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, load-balancing

I am looking to create a load balancing server. Essentially here is what I want to do:

I have a public IP address, lets say 1.1.1.1 I have a second public IP address, lets say 2.2.2.2. I have a website, www.f.com point to 1.1.1.1 via an A record. I want that Ubuntu server to forward traffic like this:

- Port 80 traffic is forwarded to 2.2.2.2 on port 60,000 and port 60,001.
- Port 443 traffic is forwaded to 2.2.2.2 on port 60,010 and port 60,011.
- Port 25 traffic is forwared to 2.2.2.2 on port 60,020 and port 60,021

The port forwarding is more important then being able to load balance.

I look forward to some responses. Both server 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 are both running Ubuntu 12.04 server edition.

Comment: This seems more like a proxy setup and less of a load balancer...you can use `iptables` to do forwarding for you.

Comment: Is it necessary to keep into account whether the destination port is up? If not, iptables DNAT rules should be able to do it...

Comment: using LVS would make more sense here than iptables

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **Pound** (http://www.apsis.ch/pound). It's lightweight, easy to configure, handles https quick and efficient, and does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to load balance data. I might recomend you to use varnish. It is easy to install and set and easy to add nodes later

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serve `HTTP` or raw `TCP` traffic, `HAProxy` might be a good option to you. It satisfies all the conditions you provided above.

References:

- http://www.haproxy.org/